# How to print a given date with an abbreviated month

Tags: formatting, datetime

The best I've been able to do is with isodate. It's the only package I've been able to find that works on arbitrary dates.

```
\usepackage[orig, british, cleanlook]{isodate}
\printdate{2013-06-28}
```

produces:

```
28 June 2013
```

I'm looking to have the month abbreviated to match our existing documentation format. I would like to end up with:

```
28 Jun 2013
```

Where all the months are abreviated. I'm thinking maybe I need to make a custom language for isodate, but there must be a better way.

**Update:**

I have also looked at the datetime package's \formatdate command. Unfortunately the date comes in as a solid string and I don't have the option of splitting it to the separate fields that the command needs.

I would be satisfied with something along the lines of:

```
\formatdate{\getday{2013-06-28}}{\getmonth{2013-06-28}}{\getyear{2013-06-28}}
```

That could be defined to a new command that would be easier to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can update the English month lookup to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[orig, british, cleanlook]{isodate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/isodate
\begin{document}

\printdate{2013-06-28}% Old date format

\makeatletter
% Update English month lookup
\def\month@english{\ifcase\month\or
    Jan\or Feb\or Mar\or Apr\or May\or Jun\or
    Jul\or Aug\or Sep\or Oct\or Nov\or Dec\fi}
\makeatother

\printdate{2013-06-28}% New date format

\end{document}
```

The above suggests a global change to the English month lookup. If you want a more localized version, you could include the following in your document preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\short@month@english{\ifcase\month\or
    Jan\or Feb\or Mar\or Apr\or May\or Jun\or
    Jul\or Aug\or Sep\or Oct\or Nov\or Dec\fi}
\newcommand{\printshortdate}[1]{{%
  \let\month@english\short@month@english% Update English month lookup (locally)
  \printdate{#1}}}% Call traditional \printdate
\makeatother
```

which allows you to use `\printdate` and/or `\printshortdate` interchangably. `\printshortdate` updates `\month@english` temporarily (note the nested braces `{..}`) before calling the traditional `\printdate` macro.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! Just started with LaTeX last week, it's a very deep hole.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another answer for people that do not want to explicitly change the lookup table and use the [datetime](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/datetime/datetime.pdf) package, I suggest using the command **\shortdate**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}

\begin{document}
    \formatdate{2013}{06}{28}

    \shortdate\formatdate{2013}{06}{28}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:* To produce the same format as requested in the original question, the package datetime requires you to define a new format instead of \shortdate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}

% Define your own date format
\newdateformat{mydate}{\THEDAY\ \shortmonthname[\THEMONTH]\ \THEYEAR}

\begin{document}
    \formatdate{28}{06}{2013}

    % Use your own format
    \mydate\formatdate{28}{06}{2013}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this fashion, you may also define your date format exactly as you want it to be.

---

And here the analogous version with [datetime2](https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\begin{document}
    \DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise,monthyearsep={,\space}}
    \DTMdate{2013-06-28}

    \DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{abbr,ord=omit,monthyearsep={\space}}
    \DTMdate{2013-06-28}
\end{document}
```

*Edit:* Here, the simple option `ord=omit` removes the *th*-suffix from the ordinals.

Comment: Alternatives are nice, although this appears to add the 'th' to the numbers, which does not match the required date format.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I concentrated on the shortened month and forgot to match the format in the question. Thus, I edited the contribution in order to match the required format.